# How to apply a pagination on array of objects in couchdb using hyperledger fabric?

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric, ibm-blockchain, ibp-vscode-extension

```
  {
      "_id": "usq",
      "_rev": "5-f8e9a8853b15f0270df94c1ae71323216",
      "transactions": [
        {
          "admin_notification": [],
          "admin_status": "pending",
          "payment_amount_usd": "1",
          "sp_tx_datetime": "Feb 26, 2021, 12:22 PM",
          "sp_tx_hash": "pi_tx1",
          "sp_tx_status": "succeeded",
          "sp_tx_toAddress": "Admin",
          "tx_admin_dateTime": "-",
          "user_buyplan_days": "7 Days"
        },
        {
          "admin_notification": [],
          "admin_status": "pending",
          "payment_amount_usd": "2",
          "sp_tx_datetime": "Feb 26, 2021, 4:09 PM",
          "sp_tx_hash": "pi_tx2",
          "sp_tx_status": "succeeded",
          "sp_tx_toAddress": "Admin",
          "tx_admin_dateTime": "-",
          "user_buyplan_days": "7 Days"
        },
        {
          "admin_notification": [],
          "admin_status": "pending",
          "payment_amount_usd": "1",
          "sp_tx_datetime": "Feb 26, 2021, 12:22 PM",
          "sp_tx_hash": "pi_tx3",
          "sp_tx_status": "succeeded",
          "sp_tx_toAddress": "Admin",
          "tx_admin_dateTime": "-",
          "user_buyplan_days": "7 Days"
        }
      ],
      "user_email": "s@mail.com",
      "user_fName": "Sam",
      "user_id": "user_2304354",
      "user_lName": "Smith",
      "user_password": "Abc@123456",
      "user_type": "user",
      "~version": "CgMBFgA="
    }
```

Here I want only 2 transactions at the first time than the next ones. So I have used ***getQueryResultWithPagination*** methods But It doesn't work on a single object. So I created a view of **CouchDB**.

```
"views": {
    "tx-view": {
      "map": "function (doc) {if(doc.transactions.length > 0) {          emit(doc.transactions); }}"
    },
    "tx-view-2": {
      "map": "function (doc) { if(doc.transactions.length > 0) {      doc.transactions.forEach(function (tag) {    emit(doc.user_id, tag);  });}}"
    }
  },
```

Can I add this view into chaincode query method and create a transaction for the same?
How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at this sample contract & application?
https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/master/asset-transfer-ledger-queries

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Yes I tried! but it also applies pagination on particular documents(objects), not in an array inside objects. Can you please help me here if possible?

Comment: Not currently possible I'm afraid